# Check and see if video is available on YouTube Music using the YouTube API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hey guys I'm working on a little project to automate some of my playlists on YouTube Music, although I am running into a problem where some of the songs I am finding are available on YouTube, but not YouTube Music specifically.

Right now I am just running a check to see if the page returns a 404 which sort of works, except YouTube music likes to just auto play the next song if the requested song is unavailable so I'll need a bit more robust system.

For a bit of an example, you can go to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xge20AqKSRE) on YouTube with a video ID of `Xge20AqKSRE` on YouTube you can watch the video no problem, although it is unavailable on YouTube Music. If you try [this other link](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=Xge20AqKSRE) you get a little popup in the bottom left saying "This song is unavailable. Skipping to the next one." which is a problem since right now I'm just checking to see if the page returns a 404, which this obviously wont.

I have been digging through the YouTube API but I cannot find anything specific to YouTube Music.

Comment: "except YouTube music **likes to just auto play the next song if the requested song is unavailable** so I'll need a bit more robust system." I don't understand what you mean. Does YouTube music skip the problematic video or is blocked in some way ? Could you provide an example of playlist leading to your issue ?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison yes, I can provide a better example. If you go to [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xge20AqKSRE) with a video ID of `Xge20AqKSRE` on YouTube you can watch the video no problem, even though this video is unavailable on YouTube Music. You can try this with [this other link](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=Xge20AqKSRE), what should* happen is you get a little popup in the bottom left saying "This song is unavailable. Skipping to the next one." which is a problem since right now I'm just checking to see if the page returns a 404, which this obviously wont.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide support for knowing whether or not a given video isn't supported in YouTube Music.

However the feature you are looking for is available in my [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com), indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=music&id=F3cXzL266TE you'll receive a JSON with `available` equals to `true` if the video is available on YouTube music, `false` otherwise. That way https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=music&id=ntG3GQdY_Ok returns `available` `true` while the first link returns `available` `false`.

If you have any question don't hesitate to comment or come to the [Discord support](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/discord).