# Is the YouTube music API not activated?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to make a simple service that searches for music and informs links through YouTube music, but most packages that can search YouTube music don't work.

Is it correct that the YouTube Music API was recently omitted from the YouTube-data-API? I am very sad...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71012426/7123660) as it only says whether or not a given video is a YouTube music isn't enough I guess ? You are looming for the `Search` feature from https://music.youtube.com/ but accessible in a programmer friendly way, correct ? If so, what precisely interest you: `Top result`, `Songs`, `Videos`, `Albums`, `Featured playlists`, `Community playlists`, `Artists` (list maybe not exhaustive) ?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I asked a question because I want to find songs classified as `music` on YouTube, and I want to get information on the `title` of the song, `artist`, `album name`, `play time`, etc.

Comment: What is the `play time` of a song? The duration of the song?